# Gitlab pipeline on commit / after MR not on pipeline run

Tags: gitlab-ci

I wanna run pipeline only when someone commits into master or merges branch into master. have such a code:

```
commit_to_master_notification:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "rest of script"
  only:
    refs:
      - master
```

but when I just triger pipeline on master branch this job is stared. How to change it to start it only when someone commits into master or after merging code.

Answer (score 2):

You can start testing with [`if rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif), using [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html):

```yaml
job:
  script: echo "Only for master commits or merge"
  rules:
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"' || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
    ...
```

Comment: fyi: predefined environment variables like CI_COMMIT_BRANCH and CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME are described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

Comment: @JakobLiskow Thank you. I have edited the answer to include that link.